# pg_dump - aborting because of server version mismatch

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, dump, pg-dump

El error se genero tratando de generar el DUMP:

```sh
pg_dump -h 192.168.0.56 --no-owner -U user name_db > /var/tmp/dump.sql
```

Output:

```
pg_dump: server version: 12.3; pg_dump version: 9.2.24
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

Comment: Please translate both question and answer into English.

Answer (score -1):

SOLUCIÓN

1. Verifique la(s) versión(es) instalada(s) de pg_dump:

```sh
find / -name pg_dump -type f 2>/dev/null
```

2. Mi salida fue:

```
/usr/bin/pg_dump
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dump
```

3. Hay dos versiones instaladas. Para actualizar pg_dump con la versión más nueva:

```sh
ln -s /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump

# Si no nos deja crear el enlace agregamos el siguiente flag:
ln -s /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump --force
```

### Fuente

1. [No coincide la versión de Postgresql pg_dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836312/postgresql-9-2-pg-dump-version-mismatch) .